# Wordpress Code only showing 1 post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code:

```
<?php
    query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' );


    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
       echo '<li>';
         the_title();
       echo '</li>';
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

The code works but there are 2 posts and it's only returning the latest one.

I need it to show them all.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: Do all the posts have a title? Check the page's generated HTML and look if there's an empty `<li></li>` in there where the second post's empty title is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5');

 while( $query ->have_posts() ) : $query ->the_post();
     echo '<li>';
     the_title();
     echo '</li>';
 endwhile;

 wp_reset_postdata();
```